# countif and sumif each row without grouping

Tags: sql, sum, countif

I'm trying to figure out sumif and countif using SQL

Here is the code to start with:
       SELECT
      ItemID
    , Supplier
    , Cost
    , SalePrice
    FROM            countifExpirement

I'm trying to create this output:
[image]

First four columns already have data and i'm trying to create calculated fields  to calculate duplicate Items, Items per supplier, and cost by supplier.
Easy to create in excel. There is alot of examples to use grouping methods, but I need every row to be present.

Comment: could you give an example of what your expected result is?

Comment: Can you please share your table(s)'s definitions?

Comment: Which DBMS? How do you get count_ItemID? Why does the first itemID 10014 have a count 2 and the next 10014 a count of 3 for instance?

Comment: just fixed count column. it should show right results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Standard SQL you would use analytic functions for this. They are not available in every DBMS, however.

```
select 
  itemid, supplier, cost, saleprice, 
  count(*) over (partition by itemid) as count_itemid, 
  count(*) over (partition by supplier) as count_supplier, 
  sum(cost) over (partition by supplier) as cost_suppler
from countifexpirement;
```

Here is the same with sub-select, available in every DBMS:

```
select 
  itemid, supplier, cost, saleprice, 
  (
    select count(*) 
    from countifexpirement x 
    where x.itemid = countifexpirement.itemid
  ) as count_itemid, 
  (
    select count(*) 
    from countifexpirement x 
    where x.supplier = countifexpirement.supplier
  ) as count_supplier, 
  (
    select sum(cost)
    from countifexpirement x 
    where x.supplier = countifexpirement.supplier
  ) as cost_suppler
from countifexpirement;
```

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri: Yes, the request for count_itemid is not clear, which is why I asked for an explanation in the comment section. I suppose typos in the result image and that count_itemid shall simply count records per itemid, just as count_supplier counts records per supplier.

Comment: Op has already corrected the question, so this answer seems correct.